# How to use Particle Swarm Optimization in the norm of a matrix

Tags: matlab, optimization, particles, swarm

I have the following code implementing PSO, but it is not working with the simple function: norm(A), where A is a matrix.

This is the code,

```
fun=@(X) norm([X(1,1),X(1,2); X(2,1), X(2,2)]);

rng default  % For reproducibility
lb = [-10,-15];
ub = [15,20];
nvars = 4;
x = particleswarm(fun,nvars,lb,ub)
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: `particleswarm` passes a row vector of length `nvars` to `fun`, so `X` is not a matrix.

Comment: @rinkert Would you like to give an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the notation of the function, as the entries of a vector.

```
fun=@(X) norm([X(1),X(2), X(3), X(4)]);

rng default  % For reproducibility
lb = [-10,-15];
ub = [15,20];
nvars = 4;
x = particleswarm(fun,nvars,lb,ub)
```